# Changing the environment if it sees the incorrect environment in the setting

Tags: javascript

I am using the function below to change the environment. If it sees the wrong environment values, it clicks on it and it changes the environment.

In this function, I am just using if and else statement. Is this a good code practice? This does the job however it does not seem clean.

```
class SettingsPage extends Page {

changeEnvironment(appName) {
        if (appName.$(PreferenceScreen.environmentProduction).isDisplayed()) {
            appName.$(PreferenceScreen.environmentProduction).click();
        }
        else if
            (appName.$(PreferenceScreen.environmentDevelopment).isDisplayed()) {
             appName.$(PreferenceScreen.environmentDevelopment).click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't switch case be better if you have limited options?

Answer (score 1):

The built in JS array transformation functions could help you reduce duplicated code.

```
const environments = ['environmentProduction','environmentDevelopment'];

class SettingsPage extends Page {
    
    changeEnvironment(appName) {
        const all_buttons = environments.map(
            env=>appName.$(PreferenceScreen[env])
        );
        const displayed_buttons = all_buttons.filter(button=>button.isDisplayed());
        displayed_buttons.forEach(button=>button.click());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go for `const displayedButton = allButtons.find(button=>button.isDisplayed());`